# Display user entered data on contact us form when validation fails in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

My controller is :

```
class ContactController < ApplicationController
     def contact_us
        @cntus = params[:post]
        if @cntus != nil
            @msg="Success"
        end
     end
end
```

Now when user entered invalid data or email verification failed, data must be present in the form what user had entered.

Comment: if you're trying to display the data after a redirect_to, params are lost. Give us more context.

Comment: You should use 'render' there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to render `new` (or `edit` if its an Update) action when it fails.

```
@cntus = params[:post]

if @cntus != nil # check @cntus.save instead (it will validate and save)
  @msg="Success"
else
  render action: :new
end
```

Make sure, your form is defined for `@cntus`

Further, you can show errors on the view (what is causing trouble in saving) like this:
It should be inside the `form_for`

```
<% if @cntus.errors.any? %>
  <div>
    <p>
      <%= pluralize(@cntus.errors.count, "error") %>
      </br>
      <%= formatted_error_messages(@cntus) %>
    </p>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Hope it helps!